# Eigenvalues of unit upper Hessenberg matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a matrix

$$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
      \times & \times & \cdots & \times  & h_1 \\
           1 & \times & \cdots & \times  & h_2 \\
             & \ddots && \vdots & \vdots \\
             &        & 1 & \times  & h_{n-1}\\
             &        &&1&h_n \end{bmatrix} $$

Where $\times s$ are prespecified and the $h_i$s are chosen.
What sets of eigenvalues can be obtained?

In the case that $\times s$ are all zeros, this is a companion matrix and you can get any prescribed eigenvalues.

Comment: 1) Instead of "chosen" you should say "variable". 2) Sorry but unless you  make numerical simulations suggesting a general result, this could be one of the billions artificial questions one can ask...

Comment: Seconding @JeanMarie's comment... both about wording and about lack of context/meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this constructively as long as the desired eigenvalues satisfy the necessary interlacing properties: [*Matrices with prescribed Ritz values*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379507004697) by Parlett and Strang